# C programs stuck on run

Tags: c

After installing windows 10 a couple of month ago i tryed to run a very simple C program, firtsly in Visual Studio 2015, and the entire IDE froze.
Then I tried compiling via command line. The build is always succesfull with no problems but when i try to run a program nothing happens, the terminal just doesn't do anything and I can't even go back. Sometimes I can't even kill the process the .exe file generated even though I'm using an admin account!

I tried the easiest program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    system("pause");     //or getchar()
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is just the flashing white underscore in a terminal that I can't even close. I've tried every compiler and every different C/C++ IDE possible, this is so strange, please help!

Comment: Sounds like something is corrupt with your operating system and/or machine. If you can't even get Visual Studio 2015 to work on Windows 10, I don't think that your problem is one for which Stack Overflow can help. Maybe ask on Super User: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus? There have been several recent questions where Avast is causing this or similar problems.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  it is missing `#include <stdlib.h>` for the call to `system()`

Comment: On my system: ubuntu linux 14.04. replaced the call to `system()` with `getchar()` as bash does not have a `pause` command.   compiled/linked with `gcc`  Then the code worked perfectly

Comment: It was avast! I already tried on another windows 10 machine with avast installed and it worked just fine so i thought the problem was something else but stopping the actual avast process just did the trick! Thanks so much @Blastfurnace

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, the programs did not run despite being compiled just fine(for the record I used mingw and win7) and I turned the avast shields off and the problem was solved. Not sure about the particular settings you need to apply to avast to keep them on and run programs normally.

Comment: The specific setting is Settings>Active Protection>File System Shield>Customize>Scan when executing>Scan programs when executing. "Untrustworthy" programs tend to freeze and make their parent process freeze when this setting is enabled.